# CMake can't build ITK

Tags: build, compilation, cmake, itk

I am trying to install ITK 4.5.0 by following the example on http://worldwidepenguin.com/2010/05/how-to-install-itk-on-a-mac-cmake-macports/ . 
I am on a mac 10.5.

As suggested, I am using CMake (2.8--12), but I am getting the error:

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".           CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built     correctly. Missing variable is: CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly. Missing variable is: CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: /Users/usr/Desktop/ITK_bin/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly. Missing variable is: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly. Missing variable is: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: /Users/usr/Desktop/ITK_bin/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add something to my path?

Answer (score 0):

Install XCode, and make sure the "make" program is available in your PATH.